# Hive from_unixtime for milliseconds

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp, epoch, milliseconds

We have a timestamp epoch column (BIGINT) stored in Hive.
We want to get Date 'yyyy-MM-dd' for this epoch.
Problem is my epoch is in milliseconds e.g. 1409535303522.
So select timestamp, from_unixtime(timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd') gives wrong results for date as it expects epoch in seconds.

So i tried dividing it by 1000. But then it gets converted to Double and we can not apply function to it. Even CAST is not working when I try to Convert this double to Bigint.

Comment: If you change the format to 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Solved it by following query:

```
select timestamp, from_unixtime(CAST(timestamp/1000 as BIGINT), 'yyyy-MM-dd') from Hadoop_V1_Main_text_archieved limit 10;
```

Comment: this does not work.. it gives an error - No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFFromUnixTime with (double, string).

Answer (score 5):

The type should be `double` to ensure precision is not lost:

```
select from_unixtime(cast(1601256179170 as double)/1000.0, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS") as event_timestamp
```

Answer (score 3):

**timestamp_ms** is unixtime in milliseconds

> SELECT from_unixtime(floor(CAST(timestamp_ms AS BIGINT)/1000), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as created_timestamp FROM table_name;

Answer (score 3):

In the original answer you'll get string, but if you'd like to get date you need to call extra cast with date:

```
select 
    timestamp, 
    cast(from_unixtime(CAST(timestamp/1000 as BIGINT), 'yyyy-MM-dd') as date) as date_col 
from Hadoop_V1_Main_text_archieved 
limit 10;
```

---

[Docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-date) for casting dates and timestamps. For converting string to date:

> `cast(string as date)`
>   If the string is in the form 'YYYY-MM-DD', then a date value corresponding to that year/month/day is returned. If the string value does not match this formate, then NULL is returned.

Date type is available only from Hive > `0.12.0` as mentioned [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types):

> `DATE` (Note: Only available starting with Hive 0.12.0)